# How does the OnCollisionEnter function work "Fundamentally"?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I am very new to c# and Unity and I have a question. I am not able to understand how OnCollisionEnter works fundamentally.

Like, if I have a terrain and a sphere hovering above it which has the rigid body component and I write:-

```
void OnCollisionEnter(Collision other)
{
    Debug.Log(other.gameObject.name);
}
```

and then run the code we on the console screen would get "Sphere" and not "Terrain". Why is Sphere being passed to "other" and not Terrain?

Secondly, I believe, OnCollisionEnter is a part of the MonoBehavior class and our class is already inheriting it from MonoBehavior.

Then, why do we have to define OnCollisionEnter() again?

These questions are really eating my head up. I will be very grateful if anyone could help me out.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Why is Sphere being passed to "other" and not Terrain?

what is passed in `other` depends on which object you attached that component to ... if you attach it to the Terrain then in `other` you should get `Sphere` and viceversa. So you see the name `other` actually kind of makes sense, right?

> Then, why do we have to define `OnCollisionEnter()` again?

in [`MonoBehaviour`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/MonoBehaviour.html) you can find [`OnCollisionEnter`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/MonoBehaviour.OnCollisionEnter.html) among al the others like `Awake`, `Update`, `Start` etc under **"Messages"**, not under "private/public/whatever **Methods**".

In very short: Messages are internally only called by the Unity process **if present** in a component and not called at all if not present.

I think they use something similar to [`Component.SendMessage`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Component.SendMessage.html) in the background but not sure.

> Calls the method named `methodName` on every `MonoBehaviour` in this game object.

Comment: Can you please explain me a bit more on What actually is a "Message" in c#? Sorry to trouble you.

Comment: And What is the differece between a Message and a Function in C# ?

Comment: @Rohan it is not actually a C# specific thing but rather something Unity "invented". In C# there doesn't exist something called Message ... only Methods (also not Function btw). As soon as you implement one of them they are Methods. It is the way **how** they are invoked that makes the difference. I honestly don't know the exact details but afaik Unity uses [Reflection](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/framework/reflection-and-codedom/reflection) in order to determin which of the MonoBehaviour "Messages" your class implements and calls them if present.

Answer (score 2):

**How it works:** "OnCollisionEnter is called when this collider/rigidbody has begun touching another rigidbody/collider" - https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Collider.OnCollisionEnter.html
OnCollisionEnter is among other functions (update, fixed update, start, awake, etc.), if defined within a body of MonoBehavior derived class, called by the Engine itself, i.e. these are engine event functions.

**Why is triggered on the Sphere:** Because you have your method in the class attached to the sphere object, see above how the OnCollisionEnter works.